# How to Escape '\' copy to Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, escaping, amazon-redshift

May I ask how to escape '\' when we copy from S3 to Redshift?

Our data contains '\' in name column and it gets uploading error, even though we use ESCAPE parameter in our copy command.

```
-- Copy Command
copy <TableName> from <Target S3 File Bucket Path>
iam_role 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' REGION 'ap-northeast-1'
REMOVEQUOTES 
IGNOREHEADER 2  
ESCAPE 
DATEFORMAT 'auto' 
TIMEFORMAT 'auto' 
GZIP 
DELIMITER ',' 
ACCEPTINVCHARS '?' 
COMPUPDATE TRUE 
STATUPDATE TRUE 
MAXERROR 0 
TRUNCATECOLUMNS  
NULL AS '\000' 
EXPLICIT_IDS;

-- Sample Data
id, name, price
234,TX35-12\,456
```

To see STL_LOAD_ERRORS, it seems to be escaped as "\\" automatically (rawline was '234,TX35-12\\,456' in STL_LOAD_ERRORS), but it can't avoid 'Delimiter not found', err_code =1214.

If something wrong with our copy command or if you have any other appropriate way, any advice would be appreciated again.

Thank you.

Comment: IF you change `234,TX35-12\,456` this to `234,TX35-12\\,456` should work. I don't know the full explanation, but something similar I did in past. `An escape` character before separator cause the issue. If it works, let me know, I'll put the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Red Boy. I tried only one issued record with \\ escape (actually, 234,TX35-12\\,456) , it had no load error anymore but 0 rows upload.

Comment: @Red Boy, Sorry, it was due to IGNOREHEADER option. Loaded successfully with \\ escape as you kindly said. If you'll put it answer, let me accept it. Thanks a lot.